# Why is OutputStream write method printed before PrintWriter's println method?

Tags: java, io, java-io

I am using an `OutputStream` and a `PrintWriter`. Here's my code:

```
  OutputStream os = System.out;
  PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(os, false);

  writer.println("Hell");
  writer.println("Hello");
  writer.println("Hello");
  writer.println("Hello");
  writer.println("Hello");
  writer.println();
  os.write("45\n".getBytes(), 0, "45\n".getBytes().length);
  writer.println();
  writer.flush();
  os.flush();
```

The output is:

```
45
Hello
Hello
Hello
Hello
Hello
```

Why is `45` printed before `Hello`'s, even though the `PrintWriter` is flushed before the `OutputStream`?

**Edit**: Please correct me If I am wrong about flushing.

Comment: Flushing only affects buffered streams. If the stream is unbuffered, then the write is sent immediately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, apperantly when calling `os.write()` you get you to a `PrintStream.write()`:

[image]

Which has `autoFlush = true` on default, whereas the PrintWriter is initialized with `autoFlush=false`.